# Failed to resolve: pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

This content below is the build.gradle in my android studio project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-script:v1-rev79-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quickstart"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I want to run project, it will show error below.Then I refer to https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
,but I still don't understand how to fix `Failed to resolve: pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0` error.

```
/Users/yayaigo/Downloads/SmsSourceCode/BroadcastReveiverNewSms/build.gradle
    Error:Error:line (21)Failed to resolve: pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0
<a href="openFile:/Users/yayaigo/Downloads/SmsSourceCode/BroadcastReveiverNewSms/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:line (25)Failed to resolve: com.google.apis:google-api-services-script:v1-rev79-1.22.0
<a href="openFile:/Users/yayaigo/Downloads/SmsSourceCode/BroadcastReveiverNewSms/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:line (22)Failed to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0
<a href="openFile:/Users/yayaigo/Downloads/SmsSourceCode/BroadcastReveiverNewSms/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

This is my environment setting below:

```
Android Studio version:2.3.2
Gradle:3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Add jcenter() in your build.gradle as follows:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the library version and it worked for me.

```
dependencies {
    // For developers using AndroidX in their applications
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
 
    // For developers using the Android Support Library
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'
}
```

Here is the link of **easypermissions** library and steps to integrate it.
https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions